# What is the axiom of unrestricted comprehension?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm attempting to learn about the axioms that constitute Naïve Set Theory as an absolute beginner to set theory. In layman's terms, what is the axiom of unrestricted comprehension?

I've looked at [this response](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/778753/971909) and [this response](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601695/axiom-of-comprehension), but the symbols employed in the responses are confusing me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unrestricted axiom of comprehension states that corresponding to every condition that we may write down, there is a set of things meeting the condition:

$$(∃y) (y=\{x : Fx\})$$

However, the fact remains that this axiom needs restriction as Russell's paradox shows that in this form it will lead to a contradiction.

You will find more in this somewhat similar post: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778753/axiom-of-unrestricted-comprehension)

Comment: Would you mind giving an example of a condition and the corresponding set of things meeting the condition?

Comment: Did you check the link?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, I referenced the post you linked in my question. I didn't get the responses for the post - hence why I am asking the question.

Comment: Let us consider the set of real numbers. Now, talk about any property that comes to your mind. Let us take the property of a number being equal to its cube. The set of reals having this property is $\{x|x=x^3\}=\{0,1,-1\}$.

Comment: Since we're working in general set theory it would be better to write $\{x\mid x\in\mathbb R \land x=x^3\}$.